# What is the order of the product of $ \frac{p-1}{p} $ under the square root of a prime?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

Is there any known asymptotical order for

$$ \prod_{p_k\ \text{prime}}^{\sqrt{p_n}} \frac{p_k-1}{p_k} $$

Comment: And I don't know how to format, can you help me ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: [Mertens' third theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems)

Comment: @DanielFischer. Wow, Mertens' third theorem is *very* pretty. I can almost see the infinite product formula for $\frac{1}{\Gamma (z)}$ in there. I wonder if that's an illusion . . . Anyway, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the third theorem of Mertens (thank you Daniel) :

$$ \prod_{p\le  n}\left(1-\frac1p\right) \sim \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln n} $$

I got :

$$ \prod_{p\leq  \sqrt{p_n}}\left(1 -\frac{1}{p}\right)\sim \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln \sqrt p_n} \sim \frac{2e^{-\gamma}}{\ln p_n} \sim \frac{2e^{-\gamma}}{\ln (n \ln n)} $$ we know that : $$ p_n\sim nln(n)$$